# Angular2 rc1 - browser back/forward buttons

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using the new RC1 router with child route.
Here is a very simple example of route configuration.

**Configuration of AppComponent**

```
@Routes([
  {path: '/area1/...', component: Area1Component},
  {path: '/page2', component: Page2Component},
  {path: '/page3', component: Page3Component}
])
```

**Configuration of Area1Component**

```
@Routes([
  {path: '/page11', component: Page11Component},
  {path: '/page12', component: Page12Component},
  {path: '/page13', component: Page13Component}
])
```

I can navigate the various pages with commands such as

```
this.router.navigate(['page2'])  // from AppComponent
```

or

```
this.router.navigate(['../page12'], this.segment) // from pages of Area1 - this.segment is the current segment
```

What I found though is that if I click the back button of the browser it brings me back for 'one page' but after that it stays there (i.e. I do not navigate back the entire history of my navigation). More, the forward button is never activated. With the old router I could go back and forth with no apparent issue.
This happens with Chrome, FF and Safari.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Same here. I submitted a comment https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7873#issuecomment-222101753